# How to get the abuse contact email from RDAP JSON using jq(1)?

Tags: jq, rdap

Having a RDAP JSON similar to [this one](https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/8.8.8.8),
how do I get the abuse email address(es) (the `vCardArray` entry/entries with the [role](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7483#section-10.2.4) set to "abuse", if there is any) using `jq(1)`? Thank you.

P.S.: Of course I tried myself but I failed completely to get what I need from the JSON. (I am mostly used to use `jq(1)` only as a pretty-printer for JSON. This is the second time I try to do something more complex than just `jq < ugly.json` with it, because I need to parse JSON very rarely in practice.)

Comment: pLease share your attempt!

Comment: @0stone0 Do you mean my desperate trial and errors attempts? If you like to see the mess...

`rdap -r 8.8.8.8 |jq 'map(select([.roles[]|contains("abuse")]|any)'`

Or, later on...

`rdap -r 8.8.8.8 |jq '.events | map(select(vCardArray[].roles == "abuse"))[0] | .roles'`

There is not much tools for these formats like JSON, YAML etc. and are very unintuitive for old-school unixer.

I had no time to learn `jq(1)`... I have to solve a real-world issue first. I will go with `sed(1)` and `awk(1)` I guess, it's single-shot action. But I wanted it to be at little more reliable, that's all...

Comment: @0stone0 I tried the step-by-step approach but didn't achieve much progress than to, in fact, always list the whole tree or somehow malformed trees. Perhaps I can use some of those tools that query JSON using SQL or I can flatten it to CSV and use ordinary unix tools to dig the information out. ?

Answer (score 2):

```
.entities[].entities[] | select(.roles | index("abuse")).vcardArray[1][] | select(.[0] == "email") | last
```

Will output `"network-abuse@google.com"` since:

- We loop over all the `.entities[].entities[]`
- Select those where `.roles` includes an index with the value `abuse`
- Get the fields from the vcardArray: `.vcardArray[1]`
- Select those where the first index `.[0]` matches `email`
- Take the last value of that array

---

#### [Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/bzINtT-5EGI)

Comment: Works. And nicely explained. I learned something. I will give `jq(1)` a try some day. For now, thank you very much.